# Connecting standalone hbase from python

Tags: python, hadoop, hbase, thrift

I am developing a python application with hbase as backend. I have installed hbase and its shell is working perfectly. Please note, I have not yet installed hadoop as I don't have nodes.But decided to use hbase because of impressive architecture.

Now the problem is, I am unable to connect to hbase from python either from libraries like happybase or directly using thrift. I tried this -  http://binesh.in/hbase/connecting-to-a-remote-standalone-hbase/ as well, but no use. Please help me on this.

Update -

```
> >>> import happybase
> >>> con =happybase.Connection('localhost') Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/happybase/api.py", line 121,
> in __init__
>     self.open()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/happybase/api.py", line 138,
> in open
>     self.transport.open()   File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 149,
> in open   File
> "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/thrift/transport/TSocket.py", line 99, in
> open thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: Could not
> connect to localhost:9090
> >>>
```

almost same prbm with directly calling. In all, I just want to use hbase database instead of mongodb in my python application. No hadoop, no hdfs etc.Is it feasible or I am trying to achieve something impossible?

Comment: What's the exact error that you are facing? Please provide python code that you have, or what exactly you have tried

Comment: jython may be one choice but heard it compromises performance.

Comment: try to replace `localhost` with your IP

Comment: thanks for reply. did, but the same error. tried 127.0.0.1 as well

Comment: Have you looked in to this [steps](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mozilla.tools.socorro/SIq24O2QMlE)

Answer (score 5):

The Trift server hast to be up and running. Your connection has to be opened as well:

```
nohup hbase thrift start &
```

Open connection in python before use. Example:

```
import happybase
connection = happybase.Connection('localhost', autoconnect=False)
connection.open()
```

Comment: You don't need to call `connection.open()` if you use the defaults.